# Metapost: define <label suffix⟩> in vardef

Tags: labels, metapost

In `label.top("foo", origin)`, `top` is label suffix. Can I pass `label suffix` by function call? Given `suffix qqaa`:

```
vardef (suffix qqaa)foo (expr ...)
  label.qqaa("whatever", origin);
enddef;
```

I don't know where `(suffix qqaa)` should put in function. And I don't know how to call `foo` to pass the label suffix.

We can define a variable in vardef, e.g., `vardef foo (expr ..., position)`. Then judge `position` by `if else` and give right suffix to label. But it will be much more convenient if we can directly pass label suffix.

The purpose is to give flexibility to user to define label position outside core function.

Comment: Did you look at the definition of the `label` function in `plain.mp`?  Could you just extend it to take a new suffix, maybe `auto`, and then  do your automatic positioning logic?   What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If all you want is to be able to move your labels a bit more than the usual amount, you could write `label("whatever", z0 shifted (a,b))`.

Comment: You might also like to read the discussion about developing a `free label` macro in the [Metafun manual](http://www.ctex.org/documents/context/metafun-p.pdf).  Section 13.2.

Comment: @ Thruston function `thefreelabel` in `Metafun` is what I want. Learn some how to define intersection point. Thank you.